# IntelliJ IDEA displaying JavaScript files with errors

Tags: javascript, jhipster, jetbrains-ide, jscs, gulp-jscs

[image]

I am new to IntelliJ Idea. When viewing `.js` files through the IDE it will display an issue with pink color in the header saying

> JSCS: Cannot find 'jscs' script file under JSCS package directory.

I have tried to solve it by configuring JSCS settings but that import doesn't work. I think that occurred due to `use strict` keyword.

So how I can resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Open File -> Settings and type jscs in the search box, then uncheck the enable checkbox. This will turn jscs off.
2. Keep it enabled. Install jscs: `npm i jscs -g` and then set JSCS Package to point to : `C:\Users\<my_user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jscs\bin\jscs` (on windows, not sure where is it installed on linux). You also need to add a .jscsrc file in the root of your project, you can find a few presets [here](http://jscs.info/overview)

Comment: I used your above mentioned first option. Thanks it works. Now JSCS issue has gone. But "jshint: use the function form of "use strict" (w097)" issue is there